# JavaFX: ComboBox cells disappear when clicked

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, imageview, scenebuilder

I'am working on a **java** project using **javafx** multiple input types.but i am having a strangle **ComboBox** behaviours since i use **Label**s with images(**ImageView**) on it.

1- Combobox looks in **white**! but i need it in black.

[image]

2- and every time **i choose an item**.

[image]
[image]

3- **it disappear!!!**

[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
...    
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

ImageView img_tun = new ImageView("images/icones/flag/Tunisia.png");
Label lbl_tun=new Label("1",img_tun);        
ImageView img_fr = new ImageView("images/icones/flag/France.png");
Label lbl_fr=new Label("2",img_fr);        
ImageView img_aut = new ImageView("images/icones/flag/World.png");
Label lbl_aut=new Label("3",img_aut);

optionsnat=FXCollections.observableArrayList(lbl_tun,lbl_fr,lbl_aut);

@FXML
ComboBox<Label> cb_nat = new ComboBox<Label>();

private String nat="1";

...

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

...

cb_nat.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
              public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number,  Number number2) {
                if(cb_nb.getItems().get((Integer) number2)=="1"){setNat("1");}
                else if(cb_nb.getItems().get((Integer) number2)=="2"){setNat("2");}
                else if(cb_nb.getItems().get((Integer) number2)=="3"){setNat("3");}
                else{System.err.println("Erreur lors de changement de nation..");}
              }
            });
    }
...
```

and `code.fxml`

```
<ComboBox fx:id="cb_nat" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="265.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
```

---

**EDIT:**

After reading this [Article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) i know that my approach is tottaly wrong and strongly not recommended.. if anyone have another ideas to put bnation flags in ComboBox please help!!

thanks..(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: I don't think enough code is shown. For example, the setNat function. And, why are you comparing an Integer to a string? Your problem is strange though

Comment: `setNat()` is a setter for `private String nat`.. but about the comparisation i took this methode as it is from internet (blame on me :p) if there is another possibility to do the same just enlight me :( i am a beginner ..
(Sorry for my english)

Comment: try to remove `= new ComboBox<Label>()`. you don't need to create an instance of ComboBox<Label>. it created at runtime by JavaFX
Application Thread.

Comment: This exact case is addressed in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) under "A warning about inserting Nodes into the ComboBox items list". The bottom line is that you should not use `Node` types as the *data* type for your `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thanks to @James_D 
it's my fault i should read that before :(
but how could i do that in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is causing this problem is that when you choose a ListCell, its item (Label in our situation) is being moved by the ComboBox from the ListCell (Items observableList) to the ButtonCell, the ButtonCell is the small box that is empty by default. However, we all know that any Node object cannot be placed twice anywhere inside the same scene, and since there is no clone function for the ListCell class, javafx removes it from its last place to the new place which is the ButtonCell.

The solution is to add strings
items in the list and provide a cell factory to create the label node inside the cell factory. Create a class called "StringImageCell" and do the following:

- You need to set the cellFactory property:
  `cb_nat.setCellFactory(listview -> new StringImageCell());`
- You need to set the buttonCell property: `cb_nat.setButtonCell(new StringImageCell());`

Here is an example:

```
     public class ComboBoxCellFactory extends Application {
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
            comboBox.getItems().addAll("1", "2", "3");
            //Set the cellFactory property
            comboBox.setCellFactory(listview -> new StringImageCell());
            // Set the buttonCell property
            comboBox.setButtonCell(new StringImageCell());
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            root.setCenter(comboBox);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
    
        }
       
        //A Custom ListCell that displays an image and string
        static class StringImageCell extends ListCell<String> {
    
            Label label;
            static HashMap<String, Image> pictures = new HashMap<>();
    
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setItem(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item);
                    ImageView image = getImageView(item);
                    label = new Label("",image);
                    setGraphic(label);
                }
            }
    
        }
    
        private static ImageView getImageView(String imageName) {
            ImageView imageView = null;
            switch (imageName) {
                case "1":
                case "2":
                case "3":
                    if (!pictures.containsKey(imageName)) {
                    pictures.put(imageName, new Image(imageName + ".png"));
                    }
                    imageView = new ImageView(pictures.get(imageName));
                    break;
                default:
                    imageName = null;
            }
            return imageView;
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    
    }
```